# How to handle 404 on react-router-dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How I can fix my router? I am using redux to handle logout but when logout, it will direct me to 404 page then to login page. I tried to put `exact` to the routes and made the 404 route last in the list of the routes. My website has different user roles so I think the bug is related to that.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path={ROUTES.Error} element={<NotFound />} />

  <Route path={ROUTES.home} element={<Private />}>
    {pages
      .filter((page) =>
        page.hasAccess.some((role) =>
          _.isEqual(role, user?.info?.RoleCode),
        ),
      )
      .map(({ id, path, element: Element }) => (
        <>
          <Route
            key={id}
            path={ROUTES.home}
            element={<Navigate replace to="dashboard" />}
          />,
          <Route key={id} path={path} element={<Element />} />
        </>
      ))}
  </Route>
  <Route
    path=""
    element={<Public />}
    children={<Route path={ROUTES.login} element={<Login />} />}
  />
</Routes>
```

Under saga Logout

```
function* logout() {
  yield put(userSlice.actions.logoutFulfilled(null));
  socket.disconnect();
  yield new Promise(() => {
    notification.success({
      message: 'Success',
      description: 'Logout Success',
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You are conditionally rendering some routes it seems, so I'd look at that. Generally you want to ***unconditionally*** render your routes and handle the route protection as a layout route. See if this [answer](/a/66289280/8690857) helps explain route protection. Also, why are you rendering a redirect to `"dashboard"` for each protected route being mapped?

Comment: Which route is your "404" route? `<Route path={ROUTES.Error} element={<NotFound />} />`? Can you [edit] to include the "logging out" code and component as part of a complete [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese I think it is because of user roles , because when I logout , the user.info in redux is null. And I tried to access other page that has user role requirements in the login page, it directed me to the 404 page because I don't have access

Comment: So calling/dispatching `logout` doesn't effect a navigation action. Where are you logging out from? Is *that* code trying to navigate somewhere upon successful logout, or this is really it, you log out and update the Redux store (and user roles), and the UI freaks out for a moment redirecting to a route that can be matched? I still think you should update your post to include a more complete [mcve].

Comment: I tried to put setTimeout(() => (window.location = ROUTES.login), 100);  on logout function, sometimes it will not direct me to 404 page but still 404 page occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue here is that the code is *conditionally* rendering routes based on the current `user` object's roles. The protected routes are unmounted prior to any user check happening, so the UI momentarily renders the "404" route *then* the auth check occurs and redirects user to log in.

You should generally *unconditionally* render the routes so that they are always mounted and matchable, and use layout routes to render route protectors.

It's unclear what the `Private` route is doing specifically, so I'll answer by suggesting you create a `RoleWrapper` component that inspects a route's access roles against the current `user.info.RoleCode` property. If the current user has the appropriate roles then the `children` prop is rendered, otherwise a redirect to a safe, non-protected route is rendered.

```
const RoleWrapper = ({ children, roles }) => {
  const { user } = /* however the user object is accessed */

  // Handles initial mount if user object is fetched
  if (user === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  const canAccess = roles.some(
    (role) => _.isEqual(role, user?.info?.RoleCode),
  );

  return canAccess
    ? children
    : <Navigate to="/dashboard" replace />; // or any safe route
};
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route path={ROUTES.Error} element={<NotFound />} />
  <Route path={ROUTES.home} element={<Private />}>
    {pages.map(({ element: Element, hasAccess, id, path }) => (
      <Route
        key={id}
        path={path}
        element={(
          <RoleWrapper roles={hasAccess}>
            <Element />
          </RoleWrapper>
        )}
      />
    ))}
  </Route>
  <Route element={<Public />}>
    <Route path={ROUTES.login} element={<Login />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: Thank you sir @Drew Reese, actually I fixed it. I just added a OR condition on filter. I added _.isNil(user.info). But I like to try your implementation. Thank you so much . I learned a lot